# DOM not updating when changes made to an array within an array

Tags: arrays, angular, dom

I have an array, with an element of an array.

```
export class Clients {
  ClientNumber        : string;
  ClientName          : string;
  Visible:            : boolean
  Matters             : Matters[];
}

export class Matters {
  ClientNumber!            : string;
  MatterNumber!            : string;
  MatterName!              : string;
  MatterDescription!       : string;
  OpenDate!                : Date;
}
```

I have a sort function which sorts the parent array (Clients). The array is associated with an observable. So, whenever I sort the array, the DOM is updated.

However, I want to be able to sort the child array.

The sort function is called, and console.logs show the child array is updated.  However, the DOM does not show the updated array.

- I have a value in the parent array, Visible.  This is initially set to false to hide the child array.  When the user clicks on a button, the variable is set to true, and the matters display.

If, I sort the Matters array, switch visible to false, then back to true, the updated Matters array is displayed.

I have attempted to [ChangeDetectorRef] detectChanges(); but since the parent array has not changed, the DOM does not update.

---

Function which establishes the array.

```
async displayMatters(clientID: number): Promise<any> {
    this.clients = [];
    this.apiService.getAllMattersByClient(clientID).toPromise().then( c => {
      let tempMatters = c.map((x) => x);
      this.$ClientMatters = this.clientsObservable(tempMatters).subscribe( a => this.clients = a );
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    })
    return;
  }
```

getAllMattersByClient()

```
getAllMattersByClient (clientID: number): Observable<Clients[]> {
    let url = this.ERP_ODS_URL + 'clients/related/' + clientID;
    return this.http.get<Clients[]>(url)
      .pipe(
        tap(results => {
          console.log("API Clients data retrieved successully")
          this.loadingIndicator = false
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError('Matters data', [])),
      );
  }
```

HTML

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="10" id="RelatedClientSubTitle"  class="clientDisplay">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let c of clients; let i = index; " class="row">
     <tr class="subtitlebar"  >
         <td class="col-10">
            <button class="blur row" (click)="c.visible = !c.visible;">
                <div class="col-10">{{c.ClientNameLong}}</div>
                <div class="col-2" >Client Number: {{c.ClientNumber}}</div>
           </button>
        </td>
        <td class="col-2">
           <button mat-raised-button (click)="getClientMatters(c.ClientNumber); title="show matters">
              Show Matters</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="c.visible" >
       <th (click)="matterArraySort(c.ClientNumber, matterNameSortDirection)">Matter Name</th>
       <th (click)="matterArraySort(c.ClientNumber, matterOpenDateSortDirection)">Open Date</th>
    </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="c.visible" >
     <td class="row" >
        <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="6" class="matterDisplay" >
            <div *cdkVirtualFor="let m of c.Matters  ; let i = index;">
               <tr class="row" >
                  <td >{{m.MatterName}}</td>
                  <td >{{m.OpenDate | date :'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
              </tr>
            </div>
        </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

sort function
direction is a 2 digit number ([0] = field to sort, [1] = direction of sort)

```
matterArraySort(clientNumber: string, direction: number): void {
    for ( let i = 0; i < this.clients.length; i++ ) {
      if (this.clients[i].ClientNumber === clientNumber) {
        const tempDirection = String(direction)[1];
        const tempSort = String(direction)[0];
        switch (parseInt(tempSort)) {
          case this.matterNameSort:
            this.matterSortSelector = this.matterNameSort;
            if (parseInt(tempDirection) === this.up) {
              this.matterNameSortDirection--;
              this.sortDirection = this.down;
              this.clients[i].Matters.sort((a, b) => (a.MatterName < b.MatterName) ? -1 : 1 );
            } else {
              this.matterNameSortDirection++;
              this.sortDirection = this.up;
              this.clients[i].Matters.sort((a, b) => (a.MatterName < b.MatterName) ? 1 : -1 );
            }
            break;
          case this.matterOpenDateSort:
            this.matterSortSelector = this.matterOpenDateSort;
            if (parseInt(tempDirection) === this.up) {
              this.matterOpenDateSortDirection--;
              this.sortDirection = this.down;
              this.clients[i].Matters.sort((a, b) => (a.OpenDate < b.OpenDate) ? -1 : 1 );
            } else {
              this.matterOpenDateSortDirection++;
              this.sortDirection = this.up;
              this.clients[i].Matters.sort((a, b) => (a.OpenDate < b.OpenDate) ? 1 : -1 );
            }
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

If I add a console.log(this.clients), at the end matterArraySort() I can see the client[i].Matters array is sorted. It is not an issue of the sort not working, but of the DOM updating.

Comment: please add sample code

Comment: Without code is impossible help you. I imagine you has any kind of error when you say "The array is associated with an observable". If you're using subject you need use `next` to say that the observable change.

Comment: not sure what it is code would help. A few  hints If you play around with the changedetection may use the `.run(()=>...)` of the `NgZone` service. It triggers the rendering reliable. May try to set the matters property of the client object not to `Matters.sort(...)` but to `[..Matters.sort(...)]` which set it to an copy of the sorted object. In some cases the changedetection will ignore changes if the underlying object is still the same. Afaik `sort` won't change the reference